# ASP.NET Core model return zero after published system

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created simple code in ASP.NET Core (calculate salary) through following math equation:

```
get salary after retirement : [basic salary × months work count / 480]
```

When I work locally, everything is working fine. But when I publish to IIS, all operations return zero as result.

Model classes:

```
public class retirement
{
    [Display(Name ="الراتب الأساسي")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage ="حقل مطلوب")]
    public double BasicSalary { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "مدة الخدمة بالأشهر")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "حقل مطلوب")]
    public int MonthCount { get; set; }

    public double Result { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult GetRetirement()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetRetirement(retirement model)
{
    model.Result = model.BasicSalary * model.MonthCount / 480;
    return View (model);
}
```

View:

```
@model retirement

<form asp-controller="mathematical" asp-action="GetRetirement" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label asp-for="BasicSalary" class="col-lg-2"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="BasicSalary" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label asp-for="MonthCount" class="col-lg-2"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="MonthCount" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label asp-for="Result" class="col-lg-2"></label>
            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" asp-for="Result" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <hr />

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" asp-action="GetRetirement">احسب</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, I think you need to log information in `retirement model` in `HttpPost` method. You may send incorrect request from your `View` to `Controller` in IIS or you have such unhandled exception. Try to add `Information` logs in your application and investigate request/response.

Comment: @ABDULLAH ALNASSRI,  do you have any error message in devtools?

Comment: what do you mean about devtools?